# Gatsby Shopify not creating individual pages

Tags: node.js, graphql, shopify, gatsby

I am working with a basic Gatsby Shopify website template here https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/building-an-ecommerce-site-with-shopify/

I am creating a products list page and also creating product specific pages per the example. When the app completely loads after I do ***gatsby develop*** I see the allShopifyProduct call in the graphql explorer but before the build, I see the following error

```
ERROR #11321  PLUGIN

"gatsby-node.js" threw an error while running the createPages lifecycle:

Cannot read property 'allShopifyProduct' of undefined

  31 |   // Iterate over all products and create a new page using a template
  32 |   // The product "handle" is generated automatically by Shopify
> 33 |   result.data.allShopifyProduct.edges.forEach(({ node }) => {
     |               ^
  34 |     createPage({
  35 |       path: `/product/${node.handle}`,
  36 |       component: path.resolve(`./src/templates/product.js`),

File: gatsby-node.js:33:15
```

After the server loads, I see this

[image]

So because of this, I am getting a HTTP 404 when I query a specific product like this

```
http://localhost:8000/product/short-sleeve-t-shirt
```

Not sure what I am doing wrong or how to get around this.

Answer (score 1):

What ended up fixing this issue for me was that the Gatsby example was looking for API data that was no longer available in Shopify - specifically the **availableForSale** parameter.  Once I removed this from the GraphQL query example in gatsby-node.js and reran the dev build it generated the templated pages as expected.  Make sure to read the entire error that is coming back and see if you can pinpoint where it's failing for you.

Answer (score 0):

If you have followed that guide or [similar](https://github.com/ohduran/gatsby-starter-hello-world-shopify/blob/master/gatsby-config.js) you should have stored your Shopify data in [environment variables](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/environment-variables/). Gatsby, by default, uses `.env.development` file for `gatsby develop` and `.env.production` file for `gatsby build`.

If your code is working only in one environment, your issue may come because you haven't set the `.env.production` with the variables, making Gatsby unavailable to reach Shopify and unable to infer the schema to be resolved by your GraphQL query.

My guess is that you are missing the `.env.production` file. Just create it in the root of your project as `.env.development`.

Resources using `gatsby-source-shopify` plugin:

- https://github.com/AlexanderProd/gatsby-shopify-starter
- https://github.com/ecomloop/headless-starter
- https://github.com/ohduran/gatsby-starter-hello-world-shopify

Comment: I don't think this is an issue with the environment variable. I actually don't have a dev file nor prod. The grpahql editor works fine but the React page doesn't. Do you know if the code for this example is on github somewhere? https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/building-an-ecommerce-site-with-shopify/

Comment: I've updated the answer with three starters using Shopify as source